# How do I configure Nginx to serve two locations with separate root directives when only one location is path-specific?

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I am attempting to configure an Nginx server block in such a manner that it achieves two objectives:

1. To have a subdomain `example.domain.com` that serves an `index` page and pages from various paths such as `/app1` and `/app2`; with all of these pages/paths sharing a common root of `/srv/www/example`.
2. To have the subdomain in the previous objective serve pages from a path such as `/app3`, but in this case having a root of `/srv/www/example/app3/web`.

I was able to achieve the first and second objectives, but **never at the same time**. Some resources I have made use of include:

- [Programming Junk: Nginx multiple sites in subdirectories](http://programmersjunk.blogspot.com/2013/11/nginx-multiple-sites-in-subdirectories.html)
- [Martin Fjordvald: How to solve “No input file specified" with PHP and Nginx](http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2011/01/no-input-file-specified-with-php-and-nginx/)
- [CakePHP in a subdirectory using nginx (Rewrite rules?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119736/cakephp-in-a-subdirectory-using-nginx-rewrite-rules)

Here is my current configuration that is currently only serving the `index`, `/app1`, and `/app2` correctly as a result of moving the root directive up out of the `location / {` directive.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /srv/www/example;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name example.domain.com;

    location /app3/ {
        root /srv/www/example/app3/web;
        try_files @app3 @app3;
    }
    location ~ /app3/.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|svg|js|ico|)$ {
        root /srv/www/example;
    }
    location @app3 {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;                
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/example/app3/web/index.php;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /srv/www/example/app3/web;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

What do I need to change to achieve both objectives in a single server block? If there is some way to get this working with multiple server blocks that both access the same subdomain and listen on the same port that would also be acceptable.

Comment: Can you use subdomains or different ports?

Comment: I would prefer to not use an an alternate subdomain or to serve from an alternate port. The apps under this domain are a suite that belong together and I'd prefer to keep things as simple as possible for managing them. Ya know, Apache may have been warty and sluggish... but by comparison it was a breeze doing this kind of thing. Thanks for asking!